# How to set size and Transparent / Clear CMFCToolBar Button and Icon in mfc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, toolbar, cmfctoolbar

I have created some (`CMFCToolBar`) toolbars and added buttons and icons to them. I read on Microsoft's official website that `CMFCToolBar` takes 23x22 button size and 16x15 icon size (ref: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984480.aspx#CMFCToolBar::SetSizes)).

If I use 16x15 for the icons, then icons appear blurry. This is because the icons are originally with size 16x16. I used the function `SetSizes(CSize (23,23), CSize(16,16))` to change icon size but the icons do not appear right:

[image]

Is there another way to set icon and button size?

---

## Update

I called the `SetSize` function before create toolbar but the icon still appear a little blurry:

[image]

I want to know if there is a way to set Icon/button Transparent or make it clear like we can set toolbar transparent through `TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT` in `CreateEx` function.

Comment: Don't keep changing the question after you received an answer. If you have a new question, click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Sorry, wont do it again :)

Comment: I wrote both questions so no misconception is made. I will be careful for future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetSizes` is a static function that affects the complete library.

It should be called before you create any toolbar or menu object.
Best location is in `InitInstance` of you applicxation.

But my tipp: Use the sizes that are recommended! 16x15 and 23x22....

Transparency can be done with standard 32bit RGB/A bitmaps.
If you have a 16 color bitmap you should use RGB(192,192,192) as the standard color for the background. It is automatically replaced with the needed background color.

This has been [answered here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/897e71e0-b644-4f60-945c-2fe6aa137136/how-make-toolbar-icons-transparent?forum=vcmfcatl) too.

Comment: I have called SetSizes Function before create and but now the icon appear a little blur. I am editing my question. Kindly, Check for details

Comment: This is a different aspect. But i changed my answer.

Comment: Please note that in SO you should always open a new question if the new topic you want to ask covers a different aspect like in this case. The question about transparency has nothing to do with your primary question! If you don't care about such rules, your question may get down voted or may be put on hold...

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Will not do that again.

Comment: Related to the transparency issue I want to mention that I have .ico Icons and not  bitmap. In the question I added the picture where icon appears blur/ unclear. How can I do that?

Comment: @Fatema: To prevent visual artifacts, don't scale images. Besides, .ico is a container format. It can contain different types of icons, including PNG encoded icons with per-pixel alpha transparency. Also, .ico files can store one or more images. Just add images with the size(s) you plan to use.